# draw $\triangle ABC$ in which $AB=5.5$cm, $\angle C =40^{\circ}$ and $BC-AC=2.5$cm

Tags: geometry

I tried this question whole day but could not find its solution I have also not got a clue please help me in doing it

Comment: With such a terse problem statement, wholly contained in the title, you are short-changing your Readers.  Please use the body of the Question to state the problem and explain where your difficulty lies.

Answer (score 8):

Draw a triangle $ABD$ with $AB=5.5\,\mathrm{cm}$ and $\angle D=110^\circ$ and $BD=2.5\,\mathrm{cm}$. Then extend $BD$ and intersect with the line through $A$ at angle $70^\circ$ with $AD$ to find $C$.

This makes $\triangle DAC$ isosceles with $\angle C=40^\circ$ and thereby the conditions are met.

[image]

Comment: (+1) Nice solution. I took the liberty to add a diagram to improve it, I hope you do not mind.