# draw triangle $\Delta ABC$ in which $\overline{AB}=5.5$ cm, $\widehat{C} =40^{\circ}$ and $\overline{BC}-\overline{AC}=2.5$ cm

Tags: geometry

Help me doing this question
I tried this question whole day but could not find the answer

Comment: class 9 ncert problem?

Answer (score 0):

HINT.

Set $x=AC$ and use the cosine rule to get an equation for $x$.

Comment: But I want how to construct it I have no idea

Comment: Construct it with ruler and compass?

Comment: See here then: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2141127/draw-triangle-abc-in-which-ab-5-5cm-angle-c-40-circ-and-bc-ac-2-5